# Polyglossia error on setting a language

Tags: xetex, polyglossia

This simple file

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
   \setdefaultlanguage{portuguese}

\begin{document}
O modelo bond-plus.
\end{document}
```

generates the error:

```
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \unskip 
l.8 \end{document}
```

under `xelatex` which seems to be a bit cryptic. It works apparently fine with `lualatex`. Encapsulatig the term "bond-plus" inside `\emph{bond-plus}`  generates an even further cryptic error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \aftergroup 
l.7 O modelo \emph{bond-plus}
```

Is this something to be expected? I am running TL'22.

Comment: This seems to be an issue with the `portuguese` language module of `polyglossia` that only occurs with XeLaTeX. It compiles fine with LuaLaTeX and a couple of other languages I tested compiled without error with both engines.

Comment: I think I could track this down to the XeLaTeX branch in `\portuguese@hyphens` in `gloss-portuguese.ldf`, but I don't know what exactly is happening there.

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug at https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues (even if you get an answer here, this is most likely something the `polyglossia` developers will want to know about).

Answer (score 2):

polyglossia doesn't correctly terminate an \hskip, and so it takes the `plus` as a continuation and then complains that a dimension is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuguese}
\makeatletter
\def\portuguese@@@splhyphen#1{%
  \ifnum\hyphenchar \font>0%
    \kern\z@\discretionary{-}{\char\hyphenchar\the\font}{#1}%
    \nobreak\hskip\z@\relax%added relax
  \else%
    #1%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

 O modelo bond-plus. 
\end{document}
```

Side-remark: an example using the standalone class is *not* a simple file, the class is quite complicated and should only be used if really needed to demonstrate an error.

Comment: Thanks. What would be the best class to use to demonstrate such problem?

Comment: as in my example: article.

Comment: And why would this affect xelatex and not lualatex?